# Getting issue while dynamically setting value in drop down list using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an issue. I have two drop down list with same value. But when i am setting any value to first drop down list,the second one is taking that one. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Day Form :</span>
    <select class="form-control"  id="daysFrom" ng-model="daysFrom" ng-options="qua.name for qua in listOfDays track by qua.value ">
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Day To :</span>
        <select class="form-control"  id="daysTo" ng-model="daysTo" ng-options="qu.name for qu in listOfDays track by qu.value ">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here i have two drop down menu and suppose i am setting the value to first one like below.

```
 $scope.daysFrom.value=2;

$scope.listOfDays=[{
        name:'Select Day',
        value:''
    }]
    $scope.daysFrom=$scope.listOfDays[0];
    $scope.daysTo=$scope.listOfDays[0];
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=day",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
            var data={'name':obj.day_name,'value':obj.day_id};
            $scope.listOfDays.push(data);

        })
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })
```

The second one is also taking the same value which should not happen. I need to set different value to both drop down list. Please help me.

Comment: Can you show how you create the `$scope.daysFrom` and `$scope.daysTo` objects ? I suspect they are one and the same.

Comment: @Titus : Please check my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `$scope.daysFrom` and `$scope.daysTo` are references to the same object `$scope.listOfDays[0]`. Changes to any of this objects will be reflected in all of them.

To fix this, you can use `angular.copy`. Here is an example:

```
$scope.daysFrom = angular.copy($scope.listOfDays[0]);
$scope.daysTo = angular.copy($scope.listOfDays[0]);
```